# ¿De dónde viene "monsergas"?

Tags: etimología

A raíz de un comentario de James en el chat, he descubierto la palabra "**sergas**":

> [**SERGAS.**](https://books.google.es/books?id=LJBiWH_MGecC&dq=diccionario%20lengua%20castellana&hl=es&pg=PA798#v=onepage&q=sergas&f=false) S. f. p. Hazañas, proezas.

La cual, aunque fue retirada del diccionario de la RAE en 1992, estuvo incluida en el mismo durante los más de dos siglos precedentes simple y llanamente porque aparecía en el título de la obra [*Las Sergas de Esplandián*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_sergas_de_Esplandi%C3%A1n).

Nada más ver la definición, se me ha ocurrido que podía estar relacionada con la palabra "**monsergas**".

Mi teoría es que, siendo "las sergas" un relato de hazañas y proezas, podría haber derivado en "monsergas" como relato tedioso y repetitivo de las mismas. Siendo entonces las "monsergas" básicamente lo mismo que las "batallitas" que cuenta una y otra vez el abuelo, y "déjate de monsergas" lo mismo que "déjate de historias".

Pero al buscar en el DLE para confirmar, me encuentro con que está marcada como "de origen incierto":

> [**monserga**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PiXoLeL)
>   De or. inc. ←
>
> 1. f. Exposición o discurso fastidioso, pesado o repetitivo, y en ocasiones reprensivo.
> 2. f. Cosa o asunto fastidioso.
> 3. f. Enunciado confuso y embrollado.

Me he ido entonces al CORDE a buscar [ejemplos de uso de "monserga"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=monserga*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000), y no hay ninguno anterior al s. XIX, mientras que el ciclo de Amadís es del s. XVI... quizá demasiado anterior.

Por otra parte, buscando en el mismo CORDE [apariciones de "serga"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=serga*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000), parece que antiguamente era una especie de prenda, tela o tejido. ¿Quizá fuese una tela que se embrollaba con facilidad y de ahí el origen de "monserga" como relato confuso?

Dándole otro par de vueltas, he pensado que quizá podría venir del latín, dado que tanto "mons" como "erga" son vocablos latinos. Podría ser que algún texto latino comenzase por las palabras "Mons erga" y de ahí la expresión. Pero tras dos o tres búsquedas en Google no he encontrado nada concluyente.

Por último he visto que [en Etimologías de Chile referencian a Corominas](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?monserga), quien dice que podría venir de influencias francesas o catalanas sobre una supuesta raíz común para "mentira". Lo de la influencia francesa por la parte de "mon-", podría ser; pero la connotación de "mentira" sale aquí de la nada: una monserga es un relato pesado, quizá aburrido o si acaso confuso, pero nadie dice que sea un relato falso. No me convence.

Entonces, **por resumir, tenemos que "monsergas" podría venir de**:

- **"sergas" en el sentido de hazañas o proezas**, siendo "monsergas" un relato tedioso de las mismas;
- **"sergas" en el sentido de telas**, prendas o tejidos que (quizá) se embrollaban con facilidad, siendo "monsergas" una referencia a lo tedioso de trabajar con esas telas;
- **las palabras latinas "mons" y "erga"**, apareciendo juntas en algún fragmento de algún texto latino, y convirtiéndose "Mons erga" en ejemplo de relato pesado;
- **"*mensonge*", que en francés significa "mentira"**, y que de alguna manera habría derivado en "mensorga" y luego en "monserga" pero con otro significado.

Sí, sé que está todo cogido con pinzas, pero ¿existen pruebas que apoyen o invaliden alguno de estos orígenes? ¿Sabéis de alguna otra teoría?
¿Ha establecido la RAE alguna vez una etimología para "monserga", aunque luego la haya retirado?

Comment: Encontrado un texto del siglo XVIII (1796) en la [hemeroteca de la BNE](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001576289&page=2&search=monserga&lang=es). Un narrador está contando que fue corriendo a comprar un libro y tras leerlo dijo: "¿Sabe Vmd. á lo que se reduce el libro? Vaya, no quisiera acordarme. A murmurar de los estatutos gremiales, á tratarlos de travas [...], á condenar los gastos de entradas [...], á descubrir la mala inversion de estos fondos [...]. ¿No le parece a Vmd. que es buena monserga?"

Comment: De las 99 fichas sobre "monserga" en el Fichero General, solo una trata la etimología, mencionando el origen a partir de _mensonge_. También cita que Corominas la da como de origen incierto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por lo que he estado viendo:

- El NTLLE no recoge "serga" en ninguno de los diccionarios (aunque, efectivamente, se encuentra con el significado de "tela" en el CORDE).
- La primera aparición de "monserga" en un diccionario parece ser en el de la RAE de 1843, con la única acepción de "f. Lenguaje confuso y embrollado."; esta acepción es la única en las distintas ediciones de la RAE hasta **1984** en que se añade "patraña" a la definición. Las acepciones tipo "exposición pesada y fastidiosa" son posteriores incluso.
- Para complicar un poco más las cosas, otros diccionarios del s XIX y XX incluyen otras acepciones adicionales para monserga: Salva (1846), Gaspar y Roig (1855) y Rodrígeuz Navas (1918): Negocio complicado. | Dinero.
- Sobre la etimología: en la edición de 1884 recogen "¿Del al. *mengsel*, revoltillo?"; en 1899 la dan como segura, sin los interrogantes: "Del al. *mengsel*, revoltillo de palabras"; en 1956 y 1970 "Como el fr. *mensonge*, mentira, del lat **mentionica*, ficción, de *mentio, -onis*" y en 1984: "Voz popular de etimología difícil" para ya en 1992: "De or. inc."
- El diccionario de Corominas analiza diversas hipótesis, sin decantarse por ninguna.  Al inicio del artículo **descarta** la relación con el **oc. mensorga 'mentira'** e igualmente **descarta** la propuesta de un verbo ***monsurgar** 'darse aires de señor' (derivado del galicismo monsiur = monsieur). Pero al final del artículo recoge "No he querido atenuar ni borrar nada de los argumentos con que me opuse, en el DCEC, a la etimología occitano-catalana de monserga, no sólo porque sigo poniéndola en grave duda sino porque no quiero disimular ninguno de los aspectos del problema. Sin embargo **reconozco que, en 1975, estoy mucho menos seguro de mi negativa, pues realmente yo mismo he encontrado datos que me impiden hoy negar que una forma muy semejante existió en el catalán dialectal de otros tiempos.**" ... "Parece, pues, que en alguna parte del Norte del Principado o Rosellón corrieron realmente, aunque algo raras, estas formas medievales. El problema que subsistiría es ¿cómo pudo esa forma hallar acogida en castellano y no aflorar allí hasta 3 o 400 años más tarde?" Y más adelante "**Algo recuerda las Sergas caballerescas ... pero no hay manera de explicar *mon-* y además la aparición del vocablo es muy tardía.**" y varías hipótesis adicionales: "Podría conjeturarse que venga de un nombre hipocorístico del gato...", "¿Tal vez de un **monsigata* cruzada con *serga*?",  etc.

Comment: @walen: Yo daba por supuesto que era aleman, pero parece que en realidad es neerlandés (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mengsel - https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mengsel